# 2 A conflict of libraries . ProGuard misses

Tags: android, proguard

In my project connected library Firebase analyst , Firebase crash, JwPlayer

Proguard-prop

```
   # Keep JWPlayer
-dontwarn com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.cast.*
-dontwarn com.longtailvideo.jwplayer.*

# Keep Picasso
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

#GSON
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

#Firebase
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

---

Error when compiling with ProGuard

```
Warning:com.google.ads.afma.nano.NanoAdshieldEvent$AdShieldEvent: can't find referenced field 'int zzbqb' in program class com.google.ads.afma.nano.NanoAdshieldEvent$AdShieldEvent
Warning:com.google.ads.afma.nano.NanoAfmaSignals$AFMASignals: can't find referenced field 'int zzbqb' in program class com.google.ads.afma.nano.NanoAfmaSignals$AFMASignals
Warning:com.google.ads.afma.nano.NanoAfmaSignals$AdSignalsContainer: can't find referenced field 'int zzbqb' in program class com.google.ads.afma.nano.NanoAfmaSignals$AdSignalsContainer
Warning:there were 3 unresolved references to program class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

What does he want ?

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\AniMaunt\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\debug\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\AniMaunt\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-basement\9.4.0\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [com/google/android/gms/internal/nu.class == classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/zzv$zzb.class]))

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\AniMaunt\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\debug\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Xaker\AndroidStudioProjects\AniMaunt\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-basement\9.4.0\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [com/google/android/gms/internal/nu.class == classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/zzv$zzb.class]))
```

Comment: try com.google.ads.afma.nano.**

Comment: @ANDRO, Not wokring.
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.`